# Erratic behavior with compiled legacy code using ifort

Tags: macos, fortran, intel-fortran, intel-mkl, non-deterministic

How I *wish* I had a minimum working example for this!

I'm doing a bunch of linear algebra using the [HSL libraries](http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/catalogue/). I've turned on every debugging flag I can think of.

On my workstation, the final result of my "deterministic" code rarely works. Most of the time, it complains of an indexing error:

#### On my workstation (Mac OS 10.7.5 and ifort 12):

```
forrtl: severe (408): fort: (3): Subscript #1 of the array W has value 0 which is less than the lower bound of 1

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
libintlc.dylib     0000000103C83E04  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libintlc.dylib     0000000103C8259E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libifcore.dylib    00000001031FBDA1  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libifcore.dylib    000000010316BA4E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libifcore.dylib    000000010316BFB3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

#### On my laptop (Mac OS 10.10.5 and ifort 16):

```
forrtl: severe (408): fort: (3): Subscript #1 of the array A has value 0 which is less than the lower bound of 1

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
libifcore.dylib    000000010ABDCC96  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Uniform2DSimplifi  00000001068851EE  _ma48bd_                 1461  ma48d.f
Uniform2DSimplifi  000000010693619C  _solve_sparse_mat         142  solve_sparse_matrix_d.f90
Uniform2DSimplifi  000000010693A7D8  _scale_and_solve_         128  scale_and_solve_sparse_matrix_d.f90
Uniform2DSimplifi  000000010685740D  _calc_simplified_         598  calc_simplified_equations_B.f90
Uniform2DSimplifi  0000000106832176  _MAIN__                   161  uniform_2D_simplified_B.f90
Uniform2DSimplifi  000000010683175E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

(You may notice that these are actually *two different errors*, even though I haven't changed a line of code between them.)

My code runs successfully ~70% of the time using the newer version of `ifort` on my laptop, but only ~20% of the time using the older version of `ifort` on my workstation. Oddly, the times that it does work are often after a fresh compilation, and after working one time, it gives that error every time after that. One time it worked, didn't work the second time, then worked the third time. (Sometimes on my laptop, it works for the first 2-3 runs, but throws an error the fourth time.)

My own code is entirely deterministic: it's setting up solving linear algebra routines. It also calls the HSL routines, which evidently call MKL. I would assume that both HSL and MKL are deterministic -- that is, identical inputs produce identical outputs. (They don't call RAND() or do file I/O....) Still, I'm not sure.

#### Update:

I looked up line 1461 of ma48d.f:

```
     CALL MA50BD(NR,NC,NZB,JOB5,A(K+1),IRN(K+1),KEEP(IPTRD+J1),
 +               CNTL5,ICNTL5,IW(J1),IQB,NP,LA-NEWNE-KK,
 +               A(NEWNE+KK+1),IRN(NEWNE+KK+1),KEEP(IPTRL+J1),
 +               KEEP(IPTRU+J1),W,IW(M+1),INFO5,RINFO5)
```

On my laptop, it's complaining because `k` has a value `-1` (causing the error) while it normally has a value of `0` (leading to success). What's bizarre about this is that I'm giving these routines the exact same inputs, and the code appears to be deterministic, so they should execute the exact same lines...yet they don't.

### My question:

**What could be causing this erratic behavior?**

So far, I've thought of the following possibilities:

- **Internal compiler error** (Supporting evidence: the newer version of ifort seems to produce better--but even just *different*--results.)
- **Something related to the stack/heap**  (Supporting evidence: it works the first time, but not afterward.)
- **MKL (BLAS) is non-deterministic** (not likely) (Supporting evidence: the traceback points to libintlc.dylib, which is an Intel library...*possibly* related to MKL?)
- **HSL is non-deterministic** (likely??)  (Supporting evidence: the code appears to be deterministic, though at least one of the errors is in this code.)
- **Something about my installation of ifort or my configuration of Mac OS X?** (Supporting evidence: it's an old machine and something may have gone wrong somewhere?)

Comment: Sounds like an unitialized value to me. Have you tried running `valgrind` or a similar memory leak checker on your code?

Comment: MKL may (often) uses parallel execution.  Variation in the scheduling of threads may change observed behaviour for the same inputs.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, compilers are far more reliable than programmers.  That is, I would suspect the program of having a programming error unless it can be proved that bad code was generated.

This kind of error is certainly due to using an uninitialized value.  Look for a variable which is not specifically set to some value before being used.

```
program x
integer :: i, arr(10)

do while (i < 10)
   arr (i) = 0
   i = i + 1
enddo

print *, arr
end
```

Sometimes this code will set all the elements to zero.  Other times it won't change a thing.

---

A directly related, but more subtle lack-of-initialization error occurs in this logic:

```
program y
integer :: sum, i, arrA(10), arrB(10)
real :: ave(2)

do i = 1, 10
    arrA(i) = i * 343
    arrB(i) = i * 121
enddo

sum = 0
do i = 1, 10
    sum = sum + arrA(i)
enddo
ave(0) = sum / 10.0

do i = 1, 10
    sum = sum + arrB(i)
enddo
ave(1) = sum / 10.0

print *, 'Averages are', ave
end
```

No compiler warning will show up for failing to reinitialize `sum`, though this sort of error is reproducible and deterministic.

Comment: Thanks! Good thinking. I'm compiling with `-warn all -check all -check uninit` (among others). Shouldn't these flags catch those errors? If not, what flags could I pass to warn me of these errors at compile-time?

Comment: Also: I changed your code so it would compile...the differences should be purely cosmetic -- *I think*. Let me know if you think this would produce the same errors you're talking about. I also ran the code snippet with and without the checks I mentioned in my above comment. With the checks, it failed every time with a run-time error. Without the checks, it outputted ten zeros every time I ran it, a dozen times in a row.

Comment: @jvriesem:  I wrote Fortran 77 for so long, it is hard to remember the newer dialects.  Thanks for the edit.   Indeed, the revised code should exhibit the same randomish behavior.

Comment: @jvriesem:  While those sorts of warnings are a good start, there could still be uninitialized errors in the logic.  I'll add another example.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add a comment - hence the answer.

You can also try -ftrapuv (initialize stack variables to an unusual value). If you are using Intel 15 or higher you can set -init=snan. This initializes 'save'd variables to signal NaN.

Comment: Just tried the `ftrapuv` flag: no difference in the behavior.